# How to easily create vector or array in class and how to access them

Tags: c++, class, constructor

For example, `vector<double> A(5);` can return us a vector of 5 elements. Is it possible to do something similar in the `class` that we build ourselves?

For example, I have a class called Fruit. What constructor should I write such that `Fruit A(5);` can return me 5 `apples`. This means `apples` is a private member of this class and should be an array or vector with size 5. The reason why I didn't write the detail of `apples` is that I don't know how to properly declare it in the member and create it constructor.

In the end, after I create `Fruit A(5);`, can I only access the member of this array by creating a `get()` function in the class or there is a more convenient way of doing so?

Really appreciate if you can give me some advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You want store `apples` in a `vector` or `array`. Then you want to override the `[] operator` to access the thing you want. So something like:

```
class Fruit
{
  private:
    vector<apple> apple_storage;
  public:
    int& operator[](int j) {return apple_storage[j];}
};
```

Then you can easily use `A[3]` to access your `apple_storage`.

Comment: Damn, operator overriding, how could I forget! Dude, Thank you very much. It's very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Simplest strategy would be to have your class include a container.  Make it a public member if you don't want to have to write accessors for it:

```
class Fruit
{
  public:
    Fruit() { } 
    Fruit(int asize) : basket_(asize) { } 

    vector<apple> basket_ ; 
} ;
```

Then you would create it:

```
Fruit A(5) ;

// get an apple from Fruit
apple tmpapple= A.basket_[1] ;
```

Comment: Argh! Honestly, they're both bad advice. `std::vector` doesn't have a virtual destructor, so inheriting from `std::vector` is a bad idea. If `apples` are not to be manipulated outside of the class, encapsulate it, don't expose it!

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but I am not sure how it works exactly. For example, what does it mean C(size) when we even haven't defined C? Not too familiar with inheritance

Comment: @Cancan: We have defined `C` as a class member, so `C(size)` in the initialiser list means "initialise `C` by passing `size` as the argument to its constructor". Don't worry about inheritance here; as Vite says, it's a bad idea to inherit from standard containers.

Comment: @MikeSeymour, but how about this. Let's say we declare vector<double> apple; in public. Then in constructor and int main, how should I create the object that I can indeed access the double vector apple? Should I say A.apple[3]?(Assume we already have operator overriding for [])

Comment: let me rename it a little C -> basket_

Comment: @Cancan: Are you asking how to create an object and access its public members? You create the object in the usual manner, `Fruit A(5);` or whatever, and access its public members in the usual manner, `A.apple[3]`. Didn't your introductory book teach you that?

Comment: @ViteFalcon Not all inheritance is intended for polymorphism. Inherentance in C++ is frequently used for other techniques that don't require virtual destructors. Not that I'm saying it's a good idea here; I'm only saying that not having a virtual destructor doesn't necessarily mean inheriting is a bad idea.

Comment: @bames53: Indeed; losing all the useful constructors, including the one the OP specifically wants, is what makes it a not-entirely-good idea (although you can mitigate that in C++11).

Answer (score 0):

Without much details into `apple` and assuming they have a default constructor, here's a naive way.

```
class Fruits {
public:
    typedef std::vector<apple> AppleArray;
    typedef AppleArray::iterator AppleIterator;
    typedef AppleArray::const_iterator AppleConstIterator;

    Fruits(int appleCount)
        : mApples(appleCount)
    {
    }

    ~Fruits()
    {
    }

    apple& getAppleAt(size_t index)
    {
        return mApples.at(index);
    }

    const apple& getAppleAt(size_t index) const
    {
        return mApples.at(index);
    }

    AppleIterator getAppleBegin()
    {
        return mApples.begin();
    }

    AppleIterator getAppleEnd()
    {
        return mApples.end();
    }

    AppleConstIterator getAppleBegin() const
    {
        return mApples.begin();
    }

    AppleConstIterator getAppleEnd() const
    {
        return mApples.end();
    }

    size_t getAppleCount() const
    {
        return mApples.size();
    }    
private:
    std::vector<apple> mApples;
};
```

I'm assuming this is no production code and it's for purely learning C++. If you were to be designing a similar thing in real life, you'll need to consider that `Apple` is a `Fruit` and `Fruits` is more like a collection one or more fruits of which one is `Apple`. In which case your `Fruits` would be more like `std::vector<Fruit*> fruits;` and then you use a loop to initialize the number of `Apple`s you want in that list of `fruits`.